# Do pollen grains really act like a dipole?

Tags: forces, electrostatics, electricity, everyday-life, dipole

Yesterday I was solving some electric field from resnik book and one of the solutions assumed a bee to be a sphere of charge $60 \;\text{pC}$ and the grain which sticks to it as a dipole due to induction. Is it true that the grain acts as a dipole and that’s why they stick to it? And is it right to assume the bee to be a sphere?

Are these problems and their solutions realistic in the real world, like assuming them as a distinct shape and making them so simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Physicists simplify things to make a model that they can work with, so it could be ok to assume that the bee is a sphere.

The reason the grain would be like a dipole, is that if the bee were positive, negative charge (electrons) in the grain would be attracted to the end near the bee, leaving the other end positive.

The answers you would get from such a model are, of course, approximate.

Comment: Perhaps an elongated sphere. Is grain really a conductor in real life?

Comment: It depends, but a charge $q$ could be near one end and $-q$ near the other, and yes elongated sphere would be better...it's a kind of trade off between how realistic to make the model and how much harder the maths might become.

Comment: If we approximate the bee as a small flying cow, it is obviously spherical.

Comment: I don’t think a cow is spherical at least not where I live

Comment: @JohnHunter That would be a neutral bee.

Comment: @cOnnectOrTR12 Not many physicists where you live?

Answer (score 1):

Physicist would prefer to treat a bee as a point mass but as for a charged bee this would lead to infinities, a sphere is assumed.